# How to configure supervisor in docker correctly

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose, supervisord

I have a working laravel environment using docker. my projects has multiple services in different container such as redis, mongodb, mysqldb and nodejs. I want to use supervisor on my project to interact with redis for the queues and php to run the job. I have done some testing and research but I really can't make it work.

so here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    cron \
    supervisor

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure bcmath --enable-bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# install mongodb ext
RUN pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy supervisor configs
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

and my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: php
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: php
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - ./supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
    networks:
      - app-network

  #NODEJS Service
  nodejs: 
    image: node:10
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    tty: true
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysqldb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MongoDB Service
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    networks: 
      - app-network

  #Redis Service
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata: 
    driver: local
```

you might also want to see my supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
user=www
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
loglevel = INFO

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700
username=www
password=www

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock
username=www
password=www

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:php-fpm]
command = /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:ohwo-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan horizon
autostart=false
autorestart=true
user=www
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel-worker.log
```

so from that setup. when the containers is UP it seems that supervisord is not working because if I run `php artisan horizon` manually on my php container the queuing works perfectly. btw horizon is the tool i use for queuing.

and then I also try to run `supervisorctl` on my php container and I got this error `unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock no such file`

so I'm just pretty new to docker just started few months ago. I do know how to configure supervisord on linux but i can't make it work on docker.

so please pardon my stupidity :)

Comment: nothing with the question: you should put the code of `# Clear cache` inside the previous RUN command, because docker will create a new layer will all theses files. Classic issue of how grow your docker image by error

Comment: Keep in mind the Docker methodology is to have multiple containers with one process each, not some container that itself manages multiple processes. This adds a layer that doesn't play nice with a lot of container management tools.

Comment: @tadman so i did it wrong? how should I do it? should I put supervisor on deffirent container?

Comment: did you solve? In my case I have Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log' I tried copy and paste the same .conf but same :/

Comment: @S.Wasta No. i just followed what suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea here is to eliminate the supervisor and instead run whatever the supervisor used to run in several different containers. You can easily orchestrate this with `docker-compose`, for example, all running the same container with different `CMD` overrides, or the same container with a different `CMD` layer at the end to split it out. The trouble here is the supervisor won't be able to communicate the status of the processes it manages to Docker. It will always be "alive" even if all of its processes are completely trashed. Exposing those directly means you get to see they crashed.

What's best is to break out each of these services into separate containers. Since there's official pre-built ones for [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) and so on there's really no reason to build one yourself. What you want to do is translate that `supervisord` config to `docker-compose` format.

With separate containers you can do things like `docker ps` to see if your services are running correctly, they'll all be listed individually. If you need to upgrade one then you can do that easily, you just work with that one container, instead of having to pull down the whole thing.

The way you're attacking it here is treating Docker like a fancy VM, which it really isn't. What it is instead is a *process manager*, where these processes just so happen to have pre-built disk images and a security layer around them.

Compose your environment out of single-process containers and your life will be way easier both from a maintenance perspective, and a monitoring one.

If you can express this configuration as something `docker-compose` can deal with then you're one step closer to moving to a more sophisticated management layer like Kubernetes which might be the logical conclusion of this particular migration.

Comment: im also not very sure. but i just want to make `supervisord` work on my php container. yeah I agree that i have done it the wrong way but I can't find any resource on working supervisord on different container.

Comment: so you think its better to run `php artisan horizon` on my php container than installing supervisord to  do it?

Comment: I think if you want to use Docker effectively you need to abandon some preconceptions, and one of those is things like `systemd` and service managers of this sort. Let Docker do that for you. It's what it's there for. Making a container like this with a bunch of internal processes is way too complicated. Split it up into a bunch of single-purpose containers. It's annoying but it'll be way easier in the long run, *especially* if you can use off-the-shelf versions of MySQL, MongoDB etc.

Comment: Focus on building your PHP (and Node?) container(s) and then layer in the rest using pre-built official containers with the necessary configuration passed in as environment settings. This means you can pick specific versions of each dependency rather than being stuck with whatever your distribution comes with.

Comment: For example, start with [this PHP container](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and [this Node container](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) as a base for your two builds. These come with everything neat and tidy for their respective environments. If you need it there's probably a pre-built container for it, or something close enough a few `RUN` commands can fix it.

Comment: thanks for the idea although it didn't directly answer the question it fix my problem. so right now i don't have to worry about supervisor anymore :D

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on how to use docker compose instead of supervisor? Specifically how to make docker start the program again in case it stops?

Comment: @toraman Docker usually restarts containers that have failed automatically. Docker's [compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) has options on how long to wait for restarting, how to handle stalled or crashed processes, etc. The [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command also has options for this.

Comment: WOW! The answer and comment thread is really amazing to understand docker. Maybe out of context, but managing queues with laravel, if I have 15 work queues in my application, should I have 15 containers? Wouldn't it be easier to have a container with supervisord for such a case.

Comment: @SoyCésarMora No. You don't want to have containers with other layers of management inside of them. You want to have your services directly managed by your container layer, be that Docker or Kubernetes. If you have 15 queues that can't be serviced by a singular worker in different configurations, then have 15 containers. If one of these jams up you'll know, those containers will show as failed, versus the container appearing to work but being partially degraded.

Comment: @SoyCésarMora Use Docker as your process manager. Use `docker ps` and tools like that to check up on the status. Ensure each container has a useful log output you can view with `docker logs` for diagnostic purposes, or log aggregation via other tools like Loki. When stuff breaks you want to know exactly what broke, and be able to focus on the diagnostics related to that specific failure. You don't want to have to sift through a bunch of unrelated junk just to find the issue, especially in an emergency.

Comment: @SoyCésarMora If you're thinking of them as expensive resources you need to squeeze the most value out of, that's the wrong mindset. Containers are really just processes, they're not entire VMs. They are, resource wise, extremely cheap to spin up and shut down, so the cost of having 15 vs. 1 running 15 processes is nearly identical, except the 15 containers version is much more obvious and easier to manage.

Comment: I'm new to docker, I came here because of a problem with supervisord and I'm leaving with a totally different mindset. As his answer says, he was really "treating Docker like a fancy virtual machine" and he was dead wrong. I can only say thank you.

Comment: In the end, how do I create separate containers for commands I need to run within my PHP app (service)? The app is mainly an API backend (served by nginx container), but some other php-scripts need to be ran in the background (the mentioned queue workers).

Comment: This is where Docker Compose comes in. You run multiple containers, each encapsulating a specific process.

Answer (score 8):

According to [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> There can only be one `CMD` instruction in a **Dockerfile**. If you list more than one `CMD` then only the last `CMD` will take effect.

And your Dockerfile has two CMD commands so the command `php-fpm` will override

```
/usr/bin/supervisord
```

So that you can execute PHP commands but can't find supervisor's socket created in the container.

You can fix your issue by deleting the last `CMD` command related to `PHP-FPM` as you already configured **supervisor** to start it and your Dockerfile should have one `CMD` command:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: great. thanks for the info.. so how about running it on `RUN /usr/bin/supervisord` something like that? is that fine? ill try that later

Comment: RUN executes the command during build process but CMD set the default command for the container while running.

Comment: This causes the container to show permanently in the 'Restarting' state when looking at `docker-compose ps` – and consequently other services don't appear to be started internally. Running this command manually inside of the container works and the services start and are running without errors according to `supervisorctl status`.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you familiarize yourself with this simple project on github, there is a configuration for a docker with a working supervisor web interface.
https://github.com/Staniczek/supervisord-docker

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32142493)