# With docker-compose how to setup additional containers for background tasks

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have a PHP-application, which is initially an API-backend served by NGINX-container. But for this app to work I need to have some background php-scripts running (queue processing). Normally I would use `supervisor` to handle that. But as I figured out from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57564372/2054918), it's not a good practice to add supervisor to the same container. Instead, it is better to have separate containers each running the necessary jobs, and Docker itself will manage them. But now I'm struggling to understand how to do that.

My docker-compose.yml is such:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "${SERVICE_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ./storage/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
            - ./.docker/conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    php: # based on official php-fpm image
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./.env:/usr/src/app/.env
            - vendor:/usr/src/app/vendor
            - storage:/usr/src/app/storage
volumes:
    vendor:
    storage:
```

So, with my traditional thinking, I would just run the needed scripts within this `php` container (what I currently need is just `php artisan queue:work ...` command to process the queue). But how do I make separate container(s) for that? Can I somehow "inherit" (or reference) this `php` container so I could have individual `command` for them? Or do I define the duplicates of this one? I think making the duplicate would work (since `storage` can be shared between them all), but it sounds like an overhead to me, like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What I do is use `image`  in the `php` container too and use the same `image` name for other containers that I want to use the same image with. I have both a queue worker and a cron container

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer to my question is the possibility in docker-compose config to [extend](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/) other services. It could be such:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "${SERVICE_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ./storage/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
            - ./.docker/conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    php: # based on official php-fpm image
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./.env:/usr/src/app/.env
            - vendor:/usr/src/app/vendor
            - storage:/usr/src/app/storage
    php-queue-worker:
        extends:
            service: php
        command: php artisan queue:work
        restart: always
volumes:
    vendor:
    storage:
```

`php-queue-worker` will reuse the same image with the same configuration (volumes in particular), but with the specified command. If the worker fails or just exits, Docker will then restart the container due to `restart: always` config.